# asp.net sql update reports that it's working, but without real results

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, windows-server-2008

I have a long, and specific question.

I'm creating **asp.net (C#)** web application. 
I've mande an custom **DATABASE.cs** class, witch is used for all communications with the database that i have **on a real server** (not the pc that I'm developing the web appilcation), and it's working fine - no errors at all.

I've programmaticaly created a table in **formReports.aspx** and in each row, there are some information from database, displayed in (asp.net's)TextBox-es, with buttons **Save** and **Delete**. In this queston I am interested in **why the Save button doesn't work**.

Few things that might be useful to know:
-The **formReports.aspx** is shown in an other .aspx page in an **iFrame**.
-**Save** button's Click function is added like this: `btn.Click += new EventHandler(Update);` before witch I set `btn.CommandArgument` to some variables that I need to save, separated by "/".
-**Update** function is working fine, taking the buttons `CommandArgument`'s, splitting them into variables and calling **DATABASE.cs** function **Update** with those variables. 
-**Variables taken from `CommandArgument`** are ok, like I need them to be, so no error's there.
-**DATABASE.cs** is not a static class.
-In **DATABASE.cs**, I'm using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.
-I checked everything with step-by-step checking while the code was running.

Now, here is the code from DATABASE.Update:

```
public string Update(ReportContent rcOld, string newAccountCodeID, string newAmount)
{
    string queryFrom = "FROM [FinReports].[dbo].[ReportContent] ";
    string queryWhere = 
        " WHERE ReportID = '" + rcOld.ReportID +
        "' AND AccountCodeID = '" + rcOld.AccountCodeID + 
        "' AND Amount = '" + rcOld.Amount.ToString().Replace(',', '.') + "'";

    //check number of rows
    int rowCount;
    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) " + queryFrom + queryWhere;
    try { rowCount = int.Parse(Single(query)); }
    catch { throw new NotSupportedException(command.CommandText + ""); }

    //throw new NotSupportedException(query + "");

    //return if eny errors are found
    if (rowCount < 1) return "Ne postoji u bazi podataka";
    if (rowCount > 1) return "Postoji vise od 1 reda sa istim celijama";

    //update row
    query = "UPDATE [FinReports].[dbo].[ReportContent] " +
        "SET AccountCodeID = '" + newAccountCodeID + "', Amount = " + newAmount.Replace(',', '.') +
         queryWhere;

    //throw new NotSupportedException(query + "");

    //try {
    if (NonQuery(query) != 1)
        return "Greska";
    //} catch { throw new NotSupportedException(query + ""); }
    return "";
    //}catch{return "Fatalna greska"; }
}
```

The **ReportContent.cs** is a class used just to contain ReportID, AccountCodeID and Amount. When I populate the table, while creating **EACH** row, in the `CommandArgument`, I put information from this class.

`btn.CommandArgument` example: **u/1/220/43267,14** where:
u - stands for "update"
1 - stands for table row number (also a list index in the premade fetched List from **DATABASE.cs** class.
220 - stands for AccountCodeID from ReportContent (stuff rom real database)
43267,14 - stands for Amount from ReportContent (stuff rom real database)


As you can probbably tell, with `throw new NotSupportedException()` I've cought the exact **SQL query**, tried it on the real server, and it worked fine - no errors, and the row was updated.
Functions **Single()** and **NonQuery()** simply open the connection, execute ExecuteScalar(), that is ExecuteNonQuery(), and close the connection afterward - no errors there eather, they return (Single()) string from single top left cell, that is (NonQuery()) nuber of affected rows.
**THE PROBLEM:** I click the **Save button**, function **Update** from **formReport.aspx** is called, witch then calls the **DATABASE.Update** function, that returns **empty string** (""), as the row in real database **is updated**, but when I check the real database, the rows are **not affected at all**.
Everything runs smooth. I even added that the background of the table's row goes yellow if DATABASE.Update returns "" - goes red if it's not "" (it goes yellow when I click it).
How come, from my (client) side, get the information that the update is successfully done, but when I get to the real server, refresh the results, the row that I was aiming for, is not affected?

Comment: Run a profiler trace on the SQL Server, and see what commands (if any) are being sent from your .net app when you do the update.

Comment: Can you show the code for `NonQuery()`?

Comment: You should rewrite your class DATABASE.cs and start using **[parameterised queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)**. String concatenation is vulnerable to malicious Sql Injection, but also vulnerable to malformed sql, type conversion, data truncation and cannot make used of cached query plans. This change should also make it easier to debug. As has been suggested, you probably need to run a trace to check what is being executed on the server.

Comment: I will run the profiler trace on the server, and will comment again with the results. The NonQuery function:

private int NonQuery(string nonQuery)
        {
            Open();
            command.CommandText = nonQuery;
            int i;
            i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Close();
            return i;
        }
where Open() and Close() open/close the connection to the database (works fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here.
The problem cannot be seen from anything that I posted in the question.
I am sorry for the fuss, and will give an aswer so that other developers might learn something from my mistake.

When I said I was programmaticaly creating **Save** button, in **CommandArgument**, I was **putting the current text of just created TextBox as argument**, so any **Update or Delete** to database would, as parameters, have an empty string.

Now, I fixed the problem, by creating unique ID for those TextBoxes, sending it as parameter in **CommandArgument**, and then retrieving current text of that TextBox.

**The way I created the table**
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["user"] == null)
                { Server.Transfer("formMain.aspx"); return; }

```
            if (Request.QueryString["reportID"] == null)
            { //error code here 
            }

            database = new DATABASE();

            //load report from db
            reportID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["reportID"]);
            List<ReportContent> rows = database.ReportContents(reportID);

            //add rows
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
            report.Rows.Add(TRow(rows[i].AccountCodeID.ToString(),SetDecimals(rows[i].Amount.ToString()), i));
        }
    }
```

So, the **DON'T-CODE-FOR-TRow**

```
public TableRow TRow(string AccountCodeID, string Amount, int rowNo)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        Label label = new Label();
        string tbACIDID = "tbAccountCodeID" + rowNo;
        string tbAID = "tbAmount" + rowNo;

        //add row number
        label.Text = (rowNo + 1) + ".";
        cell.Controls.Add(label);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //add AccountCodeID
        TextBox tbac = new TextBox();
        tbac.ID = tbACIDID;
        tbac.Text = AccountCodeID;
        tbac.Width = 50;
        tbac.CssClass = "textbox";
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(tbac);
        cell.Attributes.Add("class", "cell");
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //add Amount
        tbam = new TextBox();
        tbam.ID = tbAID;
        tbam.Text = Amount;
        tbam.Width = 100;
        tbam.CssClass = "textbox";
        cell.Controls.Add(tbam);
        cell.Attributes.Add("class", "cell");
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //add save button
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Sacuvaj";
        btn.CssClass = "saveButton";
        btn.CommandArgument = 
            "u" + separator + 
            rowNo + separator + 
            tbac.Text + separator + 
            tbam.Text;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(Update);
        cell.Controls.Add(btn);

        //style cell
        cell.Attributes.Add("class", "tableCell");
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //style row
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "row");

        return row;
    }
```

And the **DO-CODE-FOR-TRow**

```
public TableRow TRow(string AccountCodeID, string Amount, int rowNo)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        Label label = new Label();
        string tbACIDID = "tbAccountCodeID" + rowNo;
        string tbAID = "tbAmount" + rowNo;

        //add row number
        label.Text = (rowNo + 1) + ".";
        cell.Controls.Add(label);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //add AccountCodeID
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = tbACIDID;
        tb.Text = AccountCodeID;
        tb.Width = 50;
        tb.CssClass = "textbox";
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
        cell.Attributes.Add("class", "cell");
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //add Amount
        tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = tbAID;
        tb.Text = Amount;
        tb.Width = 100;
        tb.CssClass = "textbox";
        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
        cell.Attributes.Add("class", "cell");
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //add save button
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Sacuvaj";
        btn.CssClass = "saveButton";
        btn.CommandArgument = 
            "u" + separator + 
            rowNo + separator + 
            tbACIDID + separator + 
            tbAID;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(Update);
        cell.Controls.Add(btn);

        //style cell
        cell.Attributes.Add("class", "tableCell");
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //style row
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "row");

        return row;
    }
```

So, tu sum up, it was a realy stupid mistake. But I couldn't figure it out until I tried to Delete and Insert the updated row. I hope that this "answer" will save someone's time.